# Xamarin Forms Android app just quits with no exception

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin.forms

I've got an issue at the moment where the android app just quits without exception. I've managed to trace it back to this line.

```
PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
```

I've checked all the properties and they all seem fine, no nulls etc.

I've also found this in the Debug output:

Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 (SI_TKILL) in tid 9154

I've googled this and spent the last 2 days trying various things like changing compiler options but to no avail. Is there a way to get more detailed information ? I am not familiar with the workings of Android so if its anything specific please explain in detail.

I'm using:

VS2019 community (not preview)
XF: 4.7.0.1351 (tried the latest 4.8.0.1451 but the same happens)
Android: 9.0 API 28

Running on an emulator also tried actual device.

**UPDATE 1 (logcat snips):**

```
09-20 14:09:03.764   777   777 F         : Why are we setting the target on an unoccupied slot?
--------- beginning of crash
09-20 14:09:03.764   777   777 F libc    : Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 (SI_TKILL) in tid 777, pid 777
09-20 14:09:03.790   852   852 I crash_dump32: obtaining output fd from tombstoned, type: kDebuggerdTombstone
09-20 14:09:03.790  1747  1747 I /system/bin/tombstoned: received crash request for pid 777
09-20 14:09:03.791   852   852 I crash_dump32: performing dump of process 777 (target tid = 777)
09-20 14:09:03.795   852   852 F DEBUG   : *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
09-20 14:09:03.795   852   852 F DEBUG   : Build fingerprint: 'google/sdk_gphone_x86_arm/generic_x86_arm:9/PSR1.180720.117/5875966:user/release-keys'
09-20 14:09:03.795   852   852 F DEBUG   : Revision: '0'
09-20 14:09:03.795   852   852 F DEBUG   : ABI: 'x86'
09-20 14:09:03.795   852   852 F DEBUG   : pid: 777, tid: 777
09-20 14:09:03.795   852   852 F DEBUG   : signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 (SI_TKILL), fault addr --------
09-20 14:09:03.795   852   852 F DEBUG   : Abort message: 'Why are we setting the target on an unoccupied slot?'
09-20 14:09:03.795   852   852 F DEBUG   :     eax 00000000  ebx 00000309  ecx 00000309  edx 00000006
09-20 14:09:03.796   852   852 F DEBUG   :     edi 00000309  esi c5462780
09-20 14:09:03.796   852   852 F DEBUG   :     ebp ffa9f6b8  esp ffa9f608  eip f66dfb39
09-20 14:09:03.796   852   852 F DEBUG   : 
09-20 14:09:03.796   852   852 F DEBUG   : backtrace:
09-20 14:09:03.796   852   852 F DEBUG   :     #00 pc 00000b39  [vdso:f66df000] (__kernel_vsyscall+9)
09-20 14:09:03.796   852   852 F DEBUG   :     #01 pc 0001fdf8  /system/lib/libc.so (syscall+40)
09-20 14:09:03.796   852   852 F DEBUG   :     #02 pc 00022ed3  /system/lib/libc.so (abort+115)
```

**UPDATE 2:**

So as I've said it crashes without exception when Invoking the PropertyChanged method.

Using the debugger I've inspected the properties of PropertyChanged. I've got a subscriber to this even which is in an external assembly for the Data Access Layer.

I removed this subscriber to see if that was the issue, but no, the problem remains.

I checked the subscriber again and now it states it's inside the Xamarin.Forms.Core.dll called OnPropertyChanged

I'm not sure how to debug this further.

**UPDATE 3:**

I've created another project in the hope of getting the same behaviour, but unfortunately I could not reproduce the issue, but I did notice one thing.

[image: This is the breakpoint on the new project which works.]

[image: This is the breakpoint on the broken project.]

We can clearly see the target in my broken project (second image) is NULL, any ideas how this could happen ?

Comment: if you comment out that line does the crash stop?  Have you tried wrapping it in a try/catch?  Have you tried using a crash reporting tool like appcenter.ms?

Comment: @Jason, Yes I've tried a try block but it never enters the catch. I've not considered appcenter as it seems massively overkill for an inhouse app which isn't going into the store. I've got a logcat dump, I've had a browse through but can't see anything what stands out. I'll update the question in a few mins with a snip from it.

Comment: "spent the last 2 days" - appcenter would take 5 minutes to setup and capture the crash info.  You don't have to use it in production if you don't want, but having that data on hand, even for an in-house app, could be very useful for future issues.

Comment: @Jason, I see the abort message in the above dump, but I've googled this and it returns 1 result which seems to be the source. I've no idea what it means though.

Comment: I'll set up appcenter if it will yield different results to what I get in the logcat dump.

Comment: I've setup the appcenter and it does not capture the crash. I can see the sessions but there is nothing logged. Followed the help and checked, ran with the debugger and without.

Comment: Could you share the device log ? Tools- Android - Device Log.

Comment: I've since downgraded to XF 4.7.0.968 and the problem seems to have gone. So this could well be a bug with the newer XF assemblies. I will upgrade back to the latest version of XF and get the Device Log later today.

Comment: Ok,if after you upgrade back to the latest version of XF,it doesn't  work,you could report it to [Github](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues).

Comment: @LeoZhu-MSFT please see new updates.

Answer (score 0):

It seems it makes no difference if the Target is null, I have no idea why it was null on one project and not the other.

Anyway after many hours , well days of debugging, the issue was because I was overwriting the properties of the bound object using Force.DeepCloner

I'm not sure exactly why this happens but its got something to do with how the object is used in the bindings. Once its created, using DeepCloner to overwrite "this" causes these issues.